# Do all forces of nature produce opposite force when they move?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, forces, reference-frames, equivalence-principle

I am not sure if I understand it right but as I see it any two moving charge particles must repel each other like they are not moving relative to observer that moving at the same speed as they moving,
according to this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKFzV8sVDsA
.
but accept the magnetic force and gravity there is also the strong force and the week force would they produce  force to the opposite direction as well in case they are moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force is rate of change of momentum. As total momentum is conserved and constant, as long as you stay in the same inertial reference frame, the total force is zero. This the basis of Newton's third law.

Comment: If two charge particle would be   connected with spring (no matter how the spring works)that balance with  the repel force they have on each 'that would cancel the magnetic field also when they are moving  and that because the magnetic field is only a result of time dilatation  but in this case the particle would never move

Comment: Two charges moving along the line that connects them do not feel eachother's magnetic force.